# Dump dict into existing yaml file just writes dict string representation into the file on updating using ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have the following code:

```
if os.path.exists(MyFile):
            path = Path(MyFile)
            yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
            settings = yaml.load(path)

            # update settings when file exists
            settings['a'] = myVar
            settings['b'] = otherVar
            settings['c'] = anotherOne
            yaml.dump(settings, Path(MyFile))

# myFile does not exist
else:
    settings = {'a': myvar, 'b': other, 'c': otheragain}
    yaml = YAML()
    yaml.dump(settings, Path(MyFile))
```

This workes like expected when called for the first time (thus when MyFile does not exist).
However, when calling the code again (updating the existing keys) and dump it again into the same file a `cat MyFile` shows the following:

```
{'a': myvar, 'b': other, 'c': otheragain}
```

But what I want instead is just a proper YAML format like before.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

So TL;DR: Dumping into non-existing file works like expected but "updating" or dumping a second time just writes the dict string representation into the file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens, because you use the round-trip dumper in the `else` clause (which is the default, equivalent to using `YAML(typ='rt')`), and you use the `safe` dumper in the if part (which has different defaults).

You should just make your third line read:

```
    yaml = YAML()
```

and then you'll get block-style leaf nodes instead of flow-style leaf nodes in your YAML file.